# Datanucleus. Occasional javax.jdo.JDODetachedFieldAccessException: You have just attempted to access field "linkedObject"

Tags: datanucleus

We use Java Datanucleus 5.0.2 with JDO.

We get occasional exception while several threads are retrieving the same information and NO thread is changing this particular "linkedObject" reference.

NOTE: The object is retrieved using the fetch plan and logs show that.

It is hard to write a test case for this to fail as it is a race condition. But nevertheless I want to ask if someone has experienced it?

Caused by: javax.jdo.JDODetachedFieldAccessException: You have just attempted to access field "linkedObject" yet this field was not detached when you detached the object. Either dont access this field, or detach it when detaching the object.
    at com.company.BaseClass.dnGetlinkedObject(BaseClass.java)
    at com.company.BaseClass.getLinkedObject(BaseClass.java:71)
...

I can see three threads calling this method

> ```
> private static <T> T getUniqueQueryJDO(final PersistenceManager pm, final JDOQLQuery query) throws PersistenceException {
>     try {
>         final javax.jdo.Query jdoQuery = setUpJDOQuery(pm, query);
>         jdoQuery.setUnique(true);
>         T result = null;
>         final T queryResult = (T) jdoQuery.executeWithMap(query.getMapValues());
>         if (queryResult != null) {
>             result = pm.detachCopy(queryResult);
>         }
>         jdoQuery.closeAll();
>         return result;
> }
> ```

and one of them fails randomly

BaseClass.java

> ```
> @PersistentDomainObject
> @PersistenceCapable(table = "BaseClass", detachable = TRUE)
> @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUPERCLASS_TABLE)
> @FetchGroups(
> ...
> @FetchGroup(name = FETCH_LINKED_OBJECT, members = {@Persistent(name = "linkedObject")})})
> ...
> public class BaseClass {
> ...
> public static final String FETCH_LINKED_CLASS = "FETCH_NAME";
> ...
>     @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = FALSE, columns = {@Column(name = "linkedObjectId", allowsNull = FALSE)}, nullValue = NullValue.EXCEPTION)
>     private LinkedClass linkedObject;
> ...
>     public LinkedClass getLinkedObject() {
>         return linkedObject;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: An object is detached and you tried to access that field, but that field did not have its value set at detach, hence is unknown, hence the exception. Totally predictable. Detach that field by setting the FetchPlan for detach

Comment: Hi Billy, Thank you for the answer. The object is retrieved with the fetch plan, this is code is not shown on the snippets, because it will take to much space. I will update the wording.

Comment: If the field is retrieved then you will not get that exception. That's all there is to say

Comment: Thank you for your reply Billy. As stated this error is occasional and we have verified that fetchPlan is set correctly. I just can't provide the proof of it here as it would be to much.

Comment: I have not finished my research but it looks that it has something to do with datanucleus FetchPlan. Potentially FetchPlan.getGroups() gets cleared somehow during concurrent use for the complex graph of objects.

Comment: and then answer WHY you are using a FetchPlan CONCURRENTLY? It is related to a PM, and so is not thread safe nor intended to be